# How to use mysql exportTable

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find a way to improve backup/restore performance of mysql database.
Currently our restore takes 6 hours and we are supposed to run it multiple times per hour (our CI is supposed to make a new database for every branch).

I found some information about a new, much faster way of making dumps using mysql directly instead of using mysqldump.
I am supposed to either use `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` if I need data only, or `util.exportTable` if I want data + structure.

```
SELECT * FROM wh.admin_users INTO OUTFILE "/var/lib/mysql-files/wh_users_1.tsv";
util.exportTable("wh.admin_users", "file:///var/lib/mysql-files/wh_users_2.tsv");
```

The first line works fine, but the second one is giving me an error:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'util.exportTable("wh.admin_users", "file:///var/lib/mysql-files/wh_users_2.tsv")' at line 1

MySQL server version is `5.7.37-0ubuntu0.18.04.1`

Is this feature available only in MySQL 8, or am I missing something?
The syntax seems weird but that is what the documentation says:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-utilities-table-export.html

Comment: As you can [read here](https://mydbops.wordpress.com/2020/11/20/mysql-shell-dump-loading-utility/) this utility has been added with MySQL 8.0.22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the error you got, it looks like you are trying to run `util.exportTable()` in the MySQL client, or via the API. This won't work.

MySQL has developed a new client called MySQL Shell. You invoke it from the command-line with the `mysqlsh` command. This new client has many different features from the old MySQL client, which is invoked simply as `mysql`.

MySQL Shell is downloaded separately. You need to install it even if you have already installed MySQL Server that includes the `mysql` client.

I'm not sure if the `util.exportTable()` function will work with MySQL Server 5.7 (I only have MySQL 8.0 installed on my laptop these days, so I'm not going to test it), but I can't think of a reason why it wouldn't work. But you do need to run it in `mysqlsh`, not `mysql`.

Comment: I am using mysql-workbench. Does it mean that those new commands will not work with it nor with any other implementation of mysql protocol (eg. pdo-mysql in php)?

Comment: They only work in the MySQL Shell.